# Blank screen (because of not found files) in built electron and react app

Tags: reactjs, web, electron, frontend, desktop-application

i finished the development of my app, using electron and react. I need to build an executable with [electron-builder](https://www.electron.build/). When i open the .exe it throws a blank screen and these errors in the console:

[image]

I was reading a lot, and realize that people suggest to use **`HashRouter`** instead of  **`BrowserRouter`**, i did it but still not working.

Here is my react routing **`index.js`**:

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { HashRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { store } from './redux/store';
import { Home, Package } from './pages';
import { NavBar } from './shared/components';
import './index.scss';

function App() {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <NavBar/>
        <HashRouter>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" component={Home} exact/>
            <Route path="/package" component={Package} exact/>
          </Switch>
        </HashRouter>
      </Provider>
      <p id="my-creds">by @gianlop3z</p>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

And my **`electron.js`**:

```
const { default: devtools, REACT_DEVELOPER_TOOLS, REDUX_DEVTOOLS } = require('electron-devtools-installer');
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const isDev = require('electron-is-dev');
const path = require('path');

function createWindow() {
  let win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 950, height: 700,
    autoHideMenuBar: true,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false,
      enableRemoteModule: true
    }
  });
  win.loadURL(
    isDev ?
      'http://localhost:3000' :
      `file://${path.join(__dirname, '../build/index.html')}`);
};

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  };
});

app.on('ready', () => {
  createWindow();
  devtools([REACT_DEVELOPER_TOOLS,  REDUX_DEVTOOLS])
    .then(name => console.log(`DevTools was added: ${name}!`))
    .catch(e => console.error(e));
});
```

Comment: localhost:3000 application should be running , so that electron application should load that URL.

Comment: You're wrong, i only need to add "homepage": "./" to the package.json

Answer (score 1):

I thought i'll add the answer here otherwise people are going to miss the solution.

Adding `"homepage": "./"` to your `package.json` will solve the problem.

If you can't add that because you are using react for web (or something else), you can add `-c.extraMetadata.homepage=./` to your `electron builder` command.

For example:
`electron-builder build -c.extraMetadata.main=electron/main.ts -c.extraMetadata.homepage=./ -c.extraMetadata.version=1.0.0 --publish never -mw`